# git keeps using the wrong credentials for Github push

Tags: git, github

I have several repositories that I upload to Github on my Account A.

I opened a second Github account, Account B. I cloned a private repo using `https://accountb:accountbpassword@github.com/...` so it would use my Account B instead of Account A.

Now when I try to push anything to repos on my Account A, I get error 403.

> `Permission to AccountA/SomeRepo denied to AccountB`

I can't figure out how Git is deciding which user to use when pushing. If I'm in one of my repos for Account A, and I look at the remote address, it **does not** include the user in the address.

Comment: Run `git config --show-origin credential.helpers` to see if any credential helper is defined. `--show-origin` is not supported in older versions. If errors complain about it, remove it. On Windows, the Credential Manager might be used.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I didn't even know what Credential Manager is! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows. Git was pulling my Github account info from Credential Manager. Apparently, when I cloned the other repo, including the username and password in the remote address, it updated my Github credentials in Credential Manager.

I deleted the Github entry in Credential Manager, and the next time I pushed, it let me enter my login info again.

I suppose the equivalent to Credential Manager on macOS would be Keychain.

[More info here on SuperUser.](https://superuser.com/questions/1064197/how-to-switch-git-user-at-terminal)